# How do I call a Java method from C (without first calling C from Java)

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

So I understand the usual procedure to generate a C header if you want to call C from Java, but I don't understand what function call I am supposed to use if I don't have a "jobject" to give. 
Like here, I'm trying to call `doSomething()`

```
public class Test {

   public void doSomething(ByteBuffer buf) { 
         System.out.println("Hi"); 
   };
}
```

I read this, but I don't get it:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16656

```
jobject buf = env->NewDirectByteBuffer(b, len);

jclass testClass;
jmethodID doSomethingMethod;

testClass = env->FindClass("test/Test");
doSomethingMethod = env->GetMethodID(testClass, "doSomething", "(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)V");
env->CallVoidMethod(buf, doSomethingMethod);
```

What is the first parameter of "CallVoidMethod()" supposed to be? It's always jobject, but what? 
When I run this, it just tells me in Eclipse "UnsupportedOperationException", it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Where do you get the env-pointer from when the code you show is not in call from Java to C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of `CallVoidMethod` is supposed to be a `jobject` referring to an instance of the class in question. You are actually passing in a byte buffer, which is a completely different thing.

You look up the class, and the method within the class, but you aren't creating (or obtaining) an actual object of that class anywhere. That is your missing step.

The byte buffer parameter to the Java method should be passed *after* the object and method parameters. Something like:

```
env->CallVoidMethod(testObj, doSomethingMethod, buf);
```

and you need to find a way of setting `testObj` to something meaningful.

---

If you actually don't want to have to instantiate an object, then you have to change the Java code to turn `doSomething()` into a `static` method.

```
public class Test {
   public static void doSomething(ByteBuffer buf) { 
         System.out.println("Hi"); 
   };
}
```

Then update your C++ code to use `GetStaticMethodID` instead of `GetMethodID`, and `CallStaticVoidMethod` instead of `CallVoidMethod`. Then you can omit that first `jobject` parameter completely.

```
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(doSomethingMethod, buf);
```

Comment: Thank you Graham. I knew in the back of my head that it was weird that I wasn't creating an object, but somehow I came to think that it was a JNI "thing".